# Unsure how to solve error in ASP.NET MVC, C#, Entity Framework form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to do a form in ASP.NET MVC using C# and Entity Framework, and I'm getting an error shown in the screenshot. It is not clear to me how to solve it, or what I should do to fix it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYAX8.png

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because one of the properties on your entity is not set to a valid value... this is usually a `TypeId` type of property... before saving look at the entity and see if any of the properties are 0 or a value that is outside of the values that are in that `Type` table.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting this error because you're trying to insert a record into a table that has a FK. Before attempting to insert data into the foreign key, it is required to first insert data into the parent table, which contains the primary key.

For example if you have a table called Users, and another table called Orders which has a FK to Users. You cannot create a record in the Orders table before the record is created on the Users table.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are trying to insert a record into a table that has a foreign key. To successfully insert data into the foreign key column, you must first insert data into the corresponding parent table, which contains the primary key.